# Failed to Invoke SignalR method

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, signalr, ws

Like the title says something went wrong when trying to invoke `JoinRoom` method from signalR.
I get the error message:

> Error: Failed to invoke 'JoinRoom' due to an error on the server.
> InvalidDataException: Error binding arguments. Make sure that the
> types of the provided values match the types of the hub method being
> invoked.

My hub:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
    {

        private readonly string _botUser;

        public ChatHub()
        {
            _botUser = "My Chat bot";
        }

        public async Task JoinRoom(UserConnection userConnection)
        {
            await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, userConnection.Room);

            await Clients.Group(userConnection.Room).SendAsync("RecieveMessage", _botUser,
            $"{userConnection.User} has joined {userConnection.Room}");

            
        }
    }
```

Trying to invoke the method in react from my app.js file:

```
const App = () => {

  const [connection, setConnection] = useState();

  const joinRoom = async (user, room) => {
    try {
      const connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl("https://localhost:7144/chat")
      .configureLogging(LogLevel.Information)
      .build();

      connection.on("RecieveMessage", (user,message) => {
        console.log("message revieced", message );
      });

      await connection.start();
      await connection.invoke("JoinRoom", (user, room));
      setConnection(connection);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }

  return <div className='app'>
    <h2>My Chat</h2>
    <hr className='line' />
    <Lobby joinRoom={joinRoom} />
  </div>
}
```

Comment: I am not a signalr expert, but in your JS function, you invoke the JoinRoom Method with two parameters, but your hub expects only one parameter

Comment: I tried to change to one parameter but still get same error

Comment: The format of the data is invalid, so the .NET cannot "deserialize" the object, how is the UserConnection class defined?

Comment: UserConnection just contains two string propertys: "User" and "Room"

Comment: Then you should change the signature of your Method to two seperate strings

Comment: Or change the parameters of the invoke on the js to match the signature of the method in the back end, so something like "await connection.invoke("JoinRoom", { property1: user, property2: room});"